# Convert c++ code to haskell

Tags: haskell

I would like to write this function in haskell

it is a union function with o(m+n) complexity

```
int printUnion(int arr1[], int arr2[], int m, int n)
{
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while(i < m && j < n)
  {
    if(arr1[i] < arr2[j])
      printf(" %d ", arr1[i++]);
    else if(arr2[j] < arr1[i])
      printf(" %d ", arr2[j++]);
    else
    {
      printf(" %d ", arr2[j++]);
      i++;
    }
  }

  /* Print remaining elements of the larger array */
  while(i < m)
   printf(" %d ", arr1[i++]);
  while(j < n)
   printf(" %d ", arr2[j++]);
}
```

Comment: Ummm... yes you would?  Seriously though, you didn't even pose a question.  Is your quesiton "Would you please do this for me?"? If so, then you misunderstand the purpose of S.O. and goal of most Haskell contributors.  Perhaps you have already tried to solve this and got stuck somewhere we could help at?

Comment: What about importing [this merge function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MissingH/0.18.6/doc/html/Data-List-Utils.html#v%3Amerge)?

Comment: This is almost a no-brainer in Haskell, obviously you should go get a basic understanding of the language first. Is this some kind of homework? Did you even try to create something like this in haskell?

Comment: @AndrewC that merge function preserves duplicate elements, whereas given a pair of lists that each contain a certain element once, the OP's code will only output that element once, not twice.

Comment: example for those who tries to learn haskell - even if it is simple one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import Control.Monad (mapM_)
```

The difference between programming languages is not just that different programming languages are different, but also that we use different programming languages differently.  e.g. C and C++ are similar programming languages, but whereas C programs tend to allocate a few large blocks of memory, C++ programs tend to allocate more but smaller blocks of memory.

So: whereas your C function takes two arrays (and has to be passed their lengths explicitly), in Haskell we would use lists instead.  (That's not to say that Haskell programs never use arrays, just as it's not true that C programs never use lists, just that C programs tend to use arrays and Haskell programs tend to use lists.)

```
showSpaced :: Show a => a -> String
showSpaced x = " " ++ show x ++ " "
```

Your C function calls `printf()`, which both formats the output and sends it to stdout, but we're going to those things separately.  `showSpaced` works with all values we can pass to `show`.

```
union :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
union xs          []          = xs
union []          ys          = ys
union xs0@(x:xs1) ys0@(y:ys1) = case x `compare` y of
    LT -> x : union xs1 ys0
    GT -> y : union xs0 ys1
    EQ -> y : union xs1 ys1
```

This `union` function requires only that the underlying elements can be compared. The two lists have to have the same type as each other. You'll note that we're using recursion instead of looping, and that by using lists instead of arrays we don't have to keep track of array indices.

We use *pattern matching*, both by giving three equations for `union` itself, and with the `case` expression.  Pattern matching is important in Haskell: find yourself a tutorial that explains it.

```
printUnion :: (Ord a, Show a) => [a] -> [a] -> IO ()
printUnion xs ys = mapM_ (putStr . showSpaced) (union xs ys)
```

And so in `printUnion` we put it all together. The list elements need to implement `Ord` (so we can call `union`) and `Show` (so we can call `showSpaced`), so they both appear in the type signature.

As you're coming from C, you may be worried about the efficiency of building up an intermediate list. Don't be: the optimiser will fuse everything into a single loop.